# Replacing part of a line of a file

Tags: python, graph

I have a digraph  coded in a .txt file (about 24k lines). Every line is in the form `sourceNode:destinationNode:edgeWeight`

I need to collapse some node into super nodes. I've a dictionary where every element is in the form 
`"superNodeName : listOfnodeNamesToCollapseIntoThisSupernode"` (the dict has 10 elements). I think the best way to "modify" the graph is to work on the .txt file.

How can I replace every occurrence in the file of the names of the nodes to collapse with the supernode name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Your super node dictionnary
super_node = {'name': [...]}

new_text = ''

# Open your txt file
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        # Split each line
        splitted = line.split(':')

        for n, n_list in super_node.items():
            if splitted[0] in n_list:  # Source is in super node
                splitted[0] = n  # Replace node name
            if splitted[1] in n_list:  # Destination is in super node
                splitted[1] = n  # Replace node name

        # Add to new text
        new_text += '{0}\n'.format(':'.join(splitted))

# Write text file
with open('text.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(new_text)
```

Comment: line  `for n, n_list in super_nodes:` gives error ValueError: too many values to unpack. Maybe I need to use `super_nodes.items(). Doing this the line `new_text.append` gives error because str object doesnt have append method

Comment: @viral I fixed it